# When I use $ sign to get Id from args, it won't work

Tags: r, shiny

`args`contains values and is.atomic(args) is TRUE, so when I use $ sign to get Id from args, it won't work.

So how do I get the values from args?

```
args <- commandArgs(T)
  print(args)

  df <- data.frame(t(args))
  print(df)
  colnames(df) <- c('ID','Region','CreatedDate','Status','TaskStatus','Comment')
  print(df)
  server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
    
    functionInput <- reactive(T)
    observe({
    if(functionInput()){
           updateTextInput(session = session,inputId = "ID",value = args$ID) 
           functionInput <<- reactive(T)
           functionSearchButton <<- reactiveVal(1)
        }else{
             functionSearchButton <<- reactiveVal(input$SearchX)
      }
   })
})
```

Comment: If it is atomic you can do `args["ID"]`.

Comment: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7295
Timing stopped at: 0 0 1.14
Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
  [No stack trace available]
There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Warning message:
closing unused RODBC handle 2

Comment: its Still the same @StéphaneLaurent

Comment: 11: execCallbacks(timeoutSecs, all, loop$id)
10: run_now(timeoutMs/1000, all = FALSE)
9: service(timeout)
8: serviceApp()
7: ..stacktracefloor..(serviceApp())
6: withCallingHandlers(expr, error = doCaptureStack)
5: domain$wrapSync(expr)
4: promises::with_promise_domain(createStackTracePromiseDomain(), 
       expr)
3: captureStackTraces({
       while (!.globals$stopped) {
           ..stacktracefloor..(serviceApp())
       }
   })
2: ..stacktraceoff..(captureStackTraces({
       while (!.globals$stopped) {
           ..stacktracefloor..(serviceApp())
       }
   }))

Comment: This showed up when i did Traceback()